# How do I parse an Angular vm variable into a number?

Tags: angularjs, parsing, casting, numbers, int

I have an Angular.js variable {{vm.gift.unclaimedamount | number}} that is cast as a number but not returning a number.

I'm trying to plug it in as a number for the Unclaimed portion of Total Spent in a drawChart function:

```
    function drawChart() {
                          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                          ['Total Spent', 'Dollars'],
                          ['Claimed', 400],
                          ['Unclaimed', a)]
                        ]);
```

How can I parse the vm variable as a number? parseInt and parseFloat aren't working

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say _parseInt and parseFloat aren't working_? Because if the value can be parsed into an int, then `parseInt` should work

Comment: You have some typos in your question. Are they in your code too? I see there is an extra parenthesis after `a`, and no closing brace at the end of your function. Where is the `a` defined?